# Clipping images using html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

i have an image drawn to a canvas. I want to clip that image and create a new image using the clipped region from the old image. How am i suppose to do that using html5 and javascript? Clipping the image will be dynamic as like used in photoshop.

```
<!--my javascroipt that draw the image to the canvas -->
<script>
 function getURLParameter(name) {
      return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
    }
    function drawImage(imageObj){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageX = 0;
        var imageY = 0;
        var imageWidth = imageObj.width;
        var imageHeight = imageObj.height;
        canvas.width = imageWidth;
        canvas.height = imageHeight;
        context.drawImage(imageObj, imageX, imageY);

    }
    var image = getURLParameter('image');
    if(image != null){
        //now put the image to the canvas lolol
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function(){
            drawImage(this);
        };
        imageObj.src = 'http://localhost/clip/temp/'+image;
    }
</script>
<!--here is my canvas..-->
<div id="container" class="unselectable">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px" class="unselectable">

    </canvas><br/>

</div>
```

now i want to clip the image. just like what photoshop clipping path is doing to an image...

Comment: You have an image drawn to a canvas, please supply us some basic JavaScript showing how you do this, as this is ALL within javascript; there is no HTML5 involved, assuming you just want to take an area of an image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can clip an image using canvas context’s drawImage with extra parameters**

This code will clip from the source image at position [clipX,clipY] that's [clipWidth x clipHeight] in size.

```
ctx.drawImage(image,clipX,clipY,clipWidth,clipHeight,0,0,clipWidth,clipHeight);
```

**Then you can save the canvas to an image using canvas.toDataURL**

This code will find an image element on the page and set it’s  src to the clipped canvas.

```
var clippedImg=document.getElementById("clipped");
clippedImg.src=canvas.toDataURL();
```

Here’s a  Fiddle that (must be viewed in Chrome/FF—not IE):  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/VJdmL/

And here’s code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:15px;}
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){

        clipImage(img,140,2,120,110);

    }
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/faces.png";

    function clipImage(image,clipX,clipY,clipWidth,clipHeight){

        // draw the image to the canvas
        // clip from the [clipX,clipY] position of the source image
        // the clipped portion will be clipWidth x clipHeight
        ctx.drawImage(image,clipX,clipY,clipWidth,clipHeight,
                        0,0,clipWidth,clipHeight);

        var clippedImg=document.getElementById("clipped");
        clippedImg.src=canvas.toDataURL();

    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Canvas (Left) and New clipped PNG (Right)</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=120 height=110></canvas>
    <img id="clipped" src="faces.png" width=120 height=110><br>
    <p>Original Image</p>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/faces.png" width=400 height=234>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for example i draw a path around the image, works like a crop but not like just recatangle... i can draw iregular shape around it and then after drawing the shape i want to copy/clip the area then save it to new image/canvas...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  You'll want to use JayC's answer in which you define a clipping path and then call context.clip().  Anything drawn after that will be clipped into your clipping path.  Then you can save the canvas to an image using canvas.toDataURL.

Comment: thank you also.. i can use your answer as i progress with my project... thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You jus need to create a path and then use the canvas context's clip method to define a clipping region before you draw the image. Here is an example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_2_canvas_clipping.html

More info here:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/

(Note, paths don't have to be defined by arcs; there's quite a number of path defining methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Trash/Canvas_tutorial-broken/Drawing_shapes )